# how to get return value from jQueryMobile Dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there anyway to get return value from jqueryMobile Dialog? Here is simple code of jQueryMobile docs but not work totally.

**index**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.delete-dialog-yes').click(function() {
        alert("delete-dialog-yes");
    });
    $('.delete-dialog-no').click(function() {
        alert("delete-dialog-no");
    });
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="my-page">
    <div data-role="content">   
        <a href="delete-dialog.cfm" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Show Dialog</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**dialog**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.delete-dialog-yes').click(function() {
        alert("delete-dialog-yes");
    });
    $('.delete-dialog-no').click(function() {
        alert("delete-dialog-no");
    });
}); 
</script>
<title>Dialog</title>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="delete_dialog" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Delete Item?</h1>
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this item?</p>
        <a href="#" class="delete-dialog-yes" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Yes</a>
        <a href="#" class="delete-dialog-no" data-role="button" data-theme="b">No</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<script>` tag in your dialog page does not get evaluated, because JQueryMobile loads this page dynamically, and uses just the `div data-role=page` from it. You can just delete that part.

In the `<script>` tag in your index page, you use `.click` on elements that don't yet exist, so obviously it does nothing. You can use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.delete-dialog-yes').live('click',function() {
        alert("delete-dialog-yes");
    });
    $('.delete-dialog-no').live('click',function() {
        alert("delete-dialog-no");
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me even with test values

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos/string.html